# TypeScript: Read a local file in binary mode

Tags: angular, rest, typescript

in a context of a Angular 4 app, there is a class in TypeScript to read local (client) files in binary mode ready to be sent to a web service?

In the past I've used in Javascript the FileReader but maybe in TS there is something better...

Thanks a lot.
F.

For reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: typescript is **javascript with types**. Nothing more, nothing less. APIs are the same.